# USB wireless gamepad not recognized on new laptop

Tags: windows-10, game-controller

I have a Genius Grandias 12v gamepad and it work fine on my old laptop but on this new one I am getting a driver error and a device status:

```
This device cannot start. (Code 10)

{Operation Failed}
The requested operation was unsuccessful.
```

The only difference in hardware that I can tell is that I now have USB 3 or 3.1 but other than that I am at a loss about the issue. What could be so different on this new laptop?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the
[MaxFire Grandias 12V Driver](http://us.geniusnet.com/supports/maxfire-grandias-12v#download)
from the Geniusnet Support website.

However, as the driver is only said to be certified for
"Windows 8, Windows 7, Windows Vista, Windows XP",
it might not work on Windows 10. But it's the best you can do.

Comment: I already done than, forgot to mention. Seems to work if I switch it to console mode but the buttons are all messed up

Comment: Besides I have the same OS and drivers on the other laptop too

Answer (score -2):

Put the receiver into PS3 mode (toggle the knob on the side of it), and it will work. All buttons are recognised properly.

Just posting Mihai Bratulescu's comment as a separate answer, so others will find it easier.